# How it work the language retrieval in this JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, jsp-tags

I am pretty new in JSP development and I have the following doubt. Into an old JSP page of a very old legacy project on which I am working on I can find this lines:

```
<%
    String language = (String) javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config.get(request.getSession(), javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config.FMT_LOCALE);
%>
```

So looking at the variable name (**language**) and using the debugger it appear clear to me that it contains the page language (in my specific case the value of the **language** variable is **it** that represent the italian language.

My doubt is: what exactly do the previous code? From what retrieve the language value? Is it the browser language or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the language defined **on the server** (not on the browser) for the current user session. This is noticed by reading the proper javadoc of [`Config`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config.html):

> [Config#get(HttpSession session, String name](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config.html#get%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,%20java.lang.String%29)
>
> Looks up a configuration variable in the "session" scope.
>
> The lookup of configuration variables is performed as if each scope had its own name space, that is, the same configuration variable name in one scope does not replace one stored in a different scope.
>
> [Config#FMT_LOCALE](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config.html#FMT_LOCALE)
>
> Name of configuration setting for application- (**as opposed to browser**-) based preferred locale